# Unable to call abstract class method from interface

Tags: java, class, interface, abstract

I'm having a bit of a hard time grasping the concept of programming to an interface and using abstract classes at the same time.

I have a set of "Retriever" classes which retrieve different types of data from the Internet. These retriever classes retrieve strings of JSON responses

```
public class AccountRetriever extends DataRetriever implements AccountInformation{
     List<String> getAccountInformation{
      ....
   }
}

public class BalanceRetriever extends DataRetriever implements BalanceInformation{
     List<String> getBalanceInformation{
      ....
   }
}
```

Both AccountInformation and BalanceInformation are interfaces with the methods shown in them. I am also extending from an abstract class "DataRetriever" which has a method called

```
public String getResponseAsString();
```

After instantiating these classes in my main using interfaces:

```
AccountInformation ai = new AccountRetriever(apiRequest);
List<String> aiList = ai.getAccountInformation();   <----this works
ai.getResponseAsString();      <----this doesn't work. Why??

BalanceInformation bi = new BalanceRetriever(apiRequest);
List<String> biList = bi.getBalanceInformation();   <----this works
bi.getResponseAsString();      <----this doesn't work. Why??
```

The getResponseAsString() method exists in the abstract class each of these retrievers  extend from so why am I unable to access that method? The only methods that I can access are the ones in the interface. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not all `AccountInformation` instances are instances of `DataRetriever`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These methods aren't visbale because while you construct a `AccountRetriever`, your `ai` variable is only of type `AccountInformation`, the interface which only has `getAccountInformation()` not `getResponseAsString()`

```
AccountInformation ai = new AccountRetriever(apiRequest);
List<String> aiList = ai.getAccountInformation();   <----this works
ai.getResponseAsString();      <----this doesn't work. Why??
```

But if you change the variable type to `DataRetriever` then `getAccountInformation()` will be visible but `getAccountInformation()` will not.

```
DataRetriever ai = new AccountRetriever(apiRequest);
List<String> aiList = ai.getAccountInformation();   <----this wont work
ai.getResponseAsString();      <---- this will work
```

You will need to change the variable type to `AccountRetriever` which both extends `DataRetriever` and implements `AccountInformation`

```
AccountRetriever ai = new AccountRetriever(apiRequest);
List<String> aiList = ai.getAccountInformation();   <----this will work
ai.getResponseAsString();      <---- this will work
```

Or, change your design so that both `AccountInformation` and `BalanceInformation` both extends a common interface which defines `getResponseAsString()`. And remove the abstract class all together.

```
public interface Information {
    public String getResponseAsString();
}

public interface AccountInformation extends Information {
    public List<String> getAccountInformation();
}

public interface BalanceInformation extends Information {
    public List<String> getBalanceInformation();
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this negate the whole reasoning for "programming to an interface"?

Comment: not at all. i think you got your inheritance back to front. iv edited the answer will an example of how to adjust it.  you can implement things in all sorts of different ways for different reasons. i think you just wanted a simple bottom up approach of interfaces and dont need the abstract class at all.

Comment: no problem. interfaces are cool. abstract classes i find are less useful. try not to overuse them.

Comment: I appreciate that feedback. Maybe I'm just trying to be over fancy... I am editing my code now

Answer (score 0):

Your's is an example of Multiple Inheritance.

*AccountRetriever* ***IS-A*** *AccountInformation* ***(implements interface)***

*AccountRetriever* ***IS-A*** *DataRetriever* ***(extends abstract class)***

So an ***AccountRetriever reference*** can use methods of both *AccountInformation* and *DataRetriever*.

```
// Will work
AccountRetriever ar = new AccountRetriever(apiRequest);
List<String> arList = ar.getAccountInformation();
ar.getResponseAsString();
```

But there is ***no IS-A*** relationship between ***AccountInformation*** and ***DataRetriever***.

So ***AccountInformation reference*** cannot use methods of *DataRetriever* even though it may contain *AccountRetriever* instance *(through upcasting)*.

```
// Won't Work
AccountInformation ai = new AccountRetriever(apiRequest); //upcasting
ai.getResponseAsString(); //error
```

The same logic applies for the case of ***BalanceRetriever***, ***BalanceInformation*** and ***DataRetriever*** as well.

```
// Will work
BalanceRetriever br = new BalanceRetriever(apiRequest);
List<String> brList = br.getBalanceInformation();   
br.getResponseAsString(); 

// Won't work
BalanceInformation bi = new BalanceRetriever(apiRequest); //upcasting
bi.getResponseAsString(); //error
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is essentially the same as a much simpler issue that we get a lot of questions about.  Something like this:

```
class Animal { ... }
class Dog extends Animal {
    public void bark() { ... }  // new method not inherited from Animal
}

Animal a = new Dog();
a.bark(); // ILLEGAL
```

Newer programmers can't figure out why `a.bark()` isn't legal.  The answer, of course, is that when the compiler sees `a.bark()`, it knows only that `a` is an `Animal`, so it can't be sure that `a` has a `bark` method.  The only methods allowed for `a` are the ones defined for `Animal`.  It's not allowed to know that `a` is a `Dog`--that can be checked only at run time.

Your problem is the same, although it involves more complexity.

```
AccountInformation ai = new AccountRetriever(apiRequest);
ai.getResponseAsString();      <----this doesn't work. Why??
```

`ai` is declared as `AccountInformation`; therefore, the only methods that can be used on it are the ones that are declared for the `AccountInformation` interface.  After all, you *could* declare another class that implements `AccountInformation` but doesn't extend `DataRetriever`, and `ai` could be an object of that class, in which case there would be no `getResponseString` method.

Note that if you have an `AccountInformation` object and you're sure it's also a `DataRetriever`, you can cast to it.

```
public void someMethod(ai: AccountInformation) {
    ((DataRetriever)ai).getResponseAsString();  // LEGAL
```

This would check at run time whether `ai` is a member of some class that extends `DataRetriever`, and throw an exception if it isn't.